# Is there any way to shape the svg container to its content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, leaflet

I'm developing an interactive map, where can be seen arrows. These arrows are made with SVG code. When the SVG container is clicked, a popup is showed like in the figure down below:

[image: Stations]

The main issue, is that the cointainer box (marked with solid 1px white border) act as click zone to show the popup, making it difficult to click specifically one of them when some arrows are near, like in the next example:

[image: near arrows]

So I'm trying to make the svg container like and little bigger arrow:

[image: wanted solution]

Making it easily clickable the desired arrow.

I'm not a very experienced HTML/javascript developer, so I don't know if it's possible to "shapelize" the SVG container to it content, making it with the same "arrow" shape, and if where possible, How I should proceed?

EDIT 1: A jsfiddle with an example:

I'm using the following javascript code:

```
function windArrow(speed, angle)
{    
  //var angulo = 0;
  var direction = 90-angle;
  // var speed = 20;
  var x = speed*Math.cos(deg2rad(direction)).toFixed(4);
  var y = speed*Math.sin(deg2rad(direction)).toFixed(4);
  var svgHeader = '<svg version="1.1" id="arrow_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" ><defs><marker id="arrowHead" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="1" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth"><path d="M0,0 L0,2 L2,1 z" stroke="none" fill="red"/><path stroke-width=".3" stroke="white" fill="none" d="M0,0 L0,2 L2,1 z" /></marker></defs>';
  var outerArrow = '<g class="outerArrow"> <path marker-end="url(#arrowHead)" d="M50,50 l'+x.toString()+','+y.toString()+'" /></g>';
  var innerArrow = '<g  class="innerArrow"><path marker-end="url(#arrowHead)" d="M50,50 l'+x.toString()+','+y.toString()+'" /></g>';
  var svgFoot = '</svg>';
  return svgHeader+outerArrow + '\n' + innerArrow + svgFoot;
}
document.getElementById('arrow').innerHTML = windArrow(20,45);
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/manespgav/at8y24dL/3/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say that it makes "it difficult to click specifically one of them when some arrows are near". Crop this image so that you show a problematic case, and then please show what you _want_ it to look like (just draw that using photoshop or something), describing how it want it to behave for the bits that cannot be captured in static images (e.g. if the user moves the mouse or clicks on overlapping areas)

Comment: i dont think making an arrow is possible when you want a easy solution(yes it is possible if you create a whole lot of `div's` and make them one shape together), but you can make one small div around the arrow and give it `border-radius:100%`

Comment: Just a note. Even if you make it smaller, it may still overlap (or it will not)?

Comment: @RamondeVries Border-radius:100% don't avoid the overlapping, but it improves

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you want, but you can bind onclick to svg component

```css
svg { pointer-events: none; border: 1px solid black;}
svg * { pointer-events: auto;}
#g2 { position:absolute; left:50px;}
```

```html
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="gray" onclick="console.log('clicked Gray')"/>
</svg>
<svg id=g2 height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="green" onclick="console.log('clicked Green')"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: this could be a good solution if I found how to unregister the click event of the div that contains the svg, due to this event came from the leaflet class

Comment: @manespgav true, answer updated. (you still have z order to consider, but it's another story)

Comment: Thanks you, I found the solution with your suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to fix your solution. As another answer here states, you may bind click events to the relevant element of your SVG graphics -- like an explicitly defined hitbox for the arrow, the entire arrow, the tip of it or whatever else.

Another solution, and I personally think it's the one you should be preferring -- because your SVG dimensions are seemingly arbitrary and do not make much sense considering it's just hardcoded and your arrow occupies just part of it. What you want is to correct your SVG document viewport through the use of the [`viewBox`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) attribute on your SVG elements.

The SVG specification covers it very well, but in short your problem is that your SVG has the dimensions of 100 x 100 pixels, while the arrow graphics it renders are much smaller. Remove `width` and `height` attributes from the root SVG element, add the `viewBox` attribute instead with appropriate values for the viewport (sizing it to the bounding box of your arrow graphics), and use CSS to control *rendered* dimensions of your `svg` elements on the map.

Comment: I need to let if as fixed "icon size" because the marker "drift" on zoom

Comment: It drifts on zoom because your anchor coordinates are wrong. If you think about it, you'll understand what I mean. But without you telling more about the zooming in your question I don't think I can help you further. You are dealing with a very simple problem, but we need details to help you. And it should not be comment on my answer, but you should *edit your question*.

Comment: you are right, that's because I need to use fixed height and width (currently, 100px x 100px), with iconAnchor at 50px, 50px

Answer (score 0):

Pointer Events may help you achieve more accurate click zones:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events